# MySql query two tables and add second as a property to the rows from the first table

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb-10.4

I am making a teacher interface, and i have four tables Professors, Students, All Assignments and Student Assignments (all assignments for individual students)

I want to send the professor all the students and all their assignments, but some have multiple assignments and some have none. I query all the student info from the first table and now I want every single row (student) to have a property assignments which is and array of all the assignments from the second table.

### Students

```
Name Class Grade
s1   1     A
s2   2     B
```

### Assignments

```
Name Student Status 
a1   s1      done
a2   s1      done
```

And I want to get:

```
[
{Name:s1, Class: 1, Grade: A, Assignments:[{Name:a1, Status: done}, {Name:a2, Status: done}]},
{Name:s2, Class: 2, Grade: B, Assignments:[]}
]
```

I am using nodejs (mysql module) for querying the database.

---

**UPDATE** (from the comment)

> version 10.4.11-MariaDB – pro_programmer

Comment: Lookup and try "join" in SQL statement to join the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON aggregation:

```
select s.*, 
    (
        select json_arrayagg(json_object('Name', a.name, 'Status', a.status)) 
        from assignments a 
        where a.student = s.name
    ) assignments
from students s
```

If MariaDB 10.4, where `json_arrayagg()` is not avaible (but `json_object()` is), one workaround uses `group_concat()`:

```
select s.*, 
    (
        select concat('[', group_concat(json_object('Name', a.name, 'Status', a.status), ']') 
        from assignments a 
        where a.student = s.name
    ) assignments
from students s
```

Comment: I am getting this error - #1305 - FUNCTION dku.json_arrayagg does not exist

Comment: @pro_programmer Specify PRECISE MySQL version in the question.

Comment: version
10.4.11-MariaDB

Comment: @pro_programmer `JSON_ARRAYAGG` needs 10.5.0. Is your server uprade an option?

Comment: Hmm, I will try to upgrade it. Thank you!

Comment: @pro_programmer: yes, that's your best option. In the meantime, see my updated answer for an alternative using string aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- MySQL 8+ needed
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Student Name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('Name', Name, 
                                                             'Status', Status)) Assignments
              FROM Assignments
              GROUP BY Student )
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'Name', Students.Name,
                    'Class', Students.Class,
                    'Grade', Students.Grade,
                    'Assignments', COALESCE(cte.Assignments, JSON_ARRAY()) ) full_data
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN cte USING (Name);
```

or

```sql
-- MySQL 5.7.22 needed
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'Name', Students.Name,
                    'Class', Students.Class,
                    'Grade', Students.Grade,
                    'Assignments', COALESCE(cte.Assignments, JSON_ARRAY()) ) full_data
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Student Name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('Name', Name, 
                                                           'Status', Status)) Assignments
            FROM Assignments
            GROUP BY Student ) cte USING (Name);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d749cb7caa4fbcf22ed58104d3f0cfcb)